# Вывод Группы атрибутов определенной Категории по API Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, api

пытаюсь сделать загрузку по API в выбранной Категории товара определенных Групп атрибутов. Не могу понять как вывести название Группы атрибутов выбранной категории, все Группы выводятся по API. Так выглядит структура в БД, так выводит по API.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
  class GroupsController extends Controller
   {
     public function index(Request $request)
     {
       return Groups::all();
      }


    }
```

Comment: Добавьте пример данных - что и в каком виде хотите получить

Comment: При выборе в карточке товара Категории я хочу получить список Групп присвоенных этой категории. Есть категория: -1,-2 У категории 1 Группы - Основные, Страна производитель, Диагональ экрана. А у категории 2 Группы - Основные, Формат экрана. В дальнейшем при нажатии на группу выводить список атрибутов которые ей соответствуют. Сейчас реализовано по API вывод атрибутов при выборе категории, я хочу Атрибуты разбить на подгруппы и вызывать потом.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделал вывод Групп для категории.
API Controller Групп для сравнения категории и группы и вывода

```
 public function index(Request $request)
 {
   $category_id=category_id;
  $data  = array("data"=> []);
  $success = array('success' => true);
  $status = array('status' => 200);
  $output = [];
  $result = [];

  if(is_numeric($request->input('category_id'))){

    $category_id = $request->input('category_id');
    $category = Category::find($category_id);

    if (!is_null($category) && count($category->toArray())){
    $groups = $category->groups;

    foreach($groups as $group)
    {

      unset($group['created_at']);
      unset($group['updated_at']);
      unset($group['pivot']);

      array_push($result, $group);
    }
   }
  }

  $data['data'] = $result;
  array_push($output, $data);
  array_push($output, $success);
  array_push($output, $status);

  return response()->json($output, 200);
  }
```

Прописал в модели модель Группы

```
    public function groups()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Groups::class);
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]